# getting empty field value with JavaScript in FormAssembly calculated field

Tags: javascript, forms, null

I'm pretty inexperienced with `JavaScript`, but I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be simple. I have a text input field (FieldA) in a FormAssembly form. I have another text input field that’s a calculated field (FieldB), and I want FieldB to return one value if FieldA is empty and a different value if FieldA is not empty. The formula I’m using in “Enter the calculation” looks like this:

```
if(FieldA==""){"empty"}else{"not empty");
```

When I go to the form, the result is “error” in FieldB, and adding a value to FieldA has no effect. When I do it in Preview mode, I get the additional message “There was an error computing this field.” FieldA here is tfa_40, but it seems to make no difference whether I use tfa_40 or define it as a variable and use the variable name. It also doesn’t seem to matter whether I use double quotes, null, or 0. Am I taking the wrong approach here? Is this even possible?

Comment: Please post your full JS code here.

Comment: That's all of the code. It's just an entry in the settings for the field in the FormAssembly form builder.

Comment: It's possibly more a question about FormAssembly than JS.

Comment: I don't know about Form Assembly but if it helps "==" not give the exact equalization for example if you code 1 =="1" it gives you a true but if you use "===" it gives you false. Also null, 0, or undefined are different from each other. You can check on that too. But you need to share all code for a real answer maybe...

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll try undefined and see if that works. I really did share all the code I created, but if I dig around in the auto-generated code, I suppose this could be useful?

"FieldA"

Comment: Having a little trouble with posting. I'll need to figure out what of that code might be relevant and how to post it.